# How can I explain "só que" to a non-native speaker?

Tags: significado

Very common in ptBr, **"só que"** is a set phrase and I find it hard to explain it to someone who is learning Portuguese. First of all, **is it a conjunction phrase?**  **How can I best explain its meaning and usage?** It would sound awkward to my ears to substitute "entretanto" or "todavia" for "só que" in the examples below. It may be so because "só que" is informal and very common in the spoken language whereas "todavia" and "entretanto" sound formal and bookish.

e.g.

> - "Eu pretendia ir com você. Só que, no último minuto, recebi uma notícia que meu primo havia..."
> - "Tínhamos combinado que cada um pagaria a sua. Só que ao lá chegarmos ele me disse que..."
> - "Minha esposa queria muito uma esteira rolante para se exercitar em casa. Só que o nosso apartamento é pequeno e não tem espaço suficiente.

---

Como explicar a locução **"só que"** para quem está aprendendo a língua portuguesa?

Muito utilizada em ptBR, a locução "só que" não é muito fácil de explicar.  Em primeiro lugar, **trata-se de uma locução conjuntiva?  Como explicar o seu significado?** Não soa bem aos meus ouvidos substituir "só que" por "entretanto" ou "todavia" nos exemplos abaixo.  Talvez porque "só que" é muito utilizado informalmente e "todavia" e "entretanto" soam livresco.

e.g.

> - "Eu pretendia ir com você. Só que, no último minuto, recebi uma notícia que meu primo havia..."
> - "Tínhamos combinado que cada um pagaria a sua. Só que ao lá chegarmos ele me disse que..."
> - "Minha esposa queria muito uma esteira rolante para se exercitar em casa. Só que o nosso apartamento é pequeno e não tem espaço suficiente.

Comment: This looks really similar to the English set phrase "It's just that…", in meaning and usage. (And it's practically word-for-word equivalent!) So for someone who already knows English, it might be easy to explain.

Comment: Not understanding the nuances of these phrases in Portuguese, I don't want to write a fake answer cribbed from English equivalents. But I feel like the meaning comes from the constituent words: _que_ introduces the following phrase grammatically as a separate fact, and _só_ can be understood as both diminishing the force of the statement ("há um probleminha **só**") and emphasizing the importance of the following fact ("é **só** isso, quer dizer é precisamente isso")

Comment: As a non-native Portuguese speaker (English), it seems pretty straightforward to me; só que can simply be translated as "(it's) just that". It may not make sense in every context when translated in this way, but almost every English speaker would understand the intended meaning.

Comment: @MrChasi  Yes, it has been mentioned in one of the answers. I think "it's just that" would fit in most contexts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's an adversative coordenating conjunctional periphrasis. An argument for such can be fond in the paper [*A Gramaticalização da Perífrase Conjuncional “Só Que”*](http://www.marilia.unesp.br/Home/Pesquisa/Gpel/Artigos/2004_-_Longhin-Thomazi_-_A_gramaticalizacao_da_perifrase_conjuncional_so_que.pdf) by Sanderléia Longhin-Thomaz. As to its nature and meaning, the author synthesizes (rough translation):

> *só que* is a conjunctional  item of coordinating nature that puts together an autonomous enuncation and a new circumstance, not considered until then, establishing between them a basic, highly pragmatic sense, which is the product of a cancellation between a presupposition common to the participants in the communicative interaction.

[Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/s%C3%B3) says as much:

> **Só que**
>   Introduz argumento, ideia, fato etc. que contradiz ou anula o que antes foi afirmado; mas porém: *Estava tudo pronto para o passeio, só que choveu*: *Fez tudo direitinho, só que não adiantou, a vaga tinha sido preenchida.*

It can of course only occur in the beginning of a clause, like *mas*, but unlike *porém* or *contudo* (which [may be deemed a type of adverbs](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/casos-de-sintaxe-de-adverbios-conetivos-contudo-todavia-e-porem/30270)). It cannot, however, be used in all circumstances where *mas* can; *só que* is a reaction (‘cancellation’) to a default inference from the first sentence. Where there's no inference to annul (given the common ground between between the parties), *só que* cannot be used (example from [CETEMPúblico](http://www.linguateca.pt/cetempublico/)):

> (1) A nova equipa da Luz tem ainda sérias dificuldades na concretização, **mas**/***só que** começa a convencer em relação ao trabalho realizado nos dois primeiros terços de terreno.

The periphrasis is actually relatively similar to the literal translation *it's just that*, which also has an adversative value, but the latter has different nuances in English and seems to preferably [follow an expression of negative polarity](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/214507/whats-the-meaning-of-it-is-just-that); the construction is generally *“it's not that... it's just that”*:

> (2) It is not that you do not have options, **it is just that** you cannot see them.

This kind of constructions can only marginally be translated with *só que*. You'd have to use something like *simplesmente*:

> (3) Não é que não tenhas opções, **simplesmente**/?**só que** não as consegues ver.

The reason for *só que* being marginal here is that the first clause cannot easily generate an assumption that is cancelled on the second. Notice that in the first clause, we're not just saying “you have options”, from which one could reasonably assume that you would be able to avail yourself of those options. We're actually saying that the assumption of you having no options (the previous sentence could have been “you don't know what to do”) is false or besides the point. But if we remove the negation in the first clause, we can introduce *só que*:

> (4) Tu tens opções, **só que** não as consegues ver.

Comment: "It's just that" *can* follow an expression of negative polarity, but often doesn't.

Comment: You  missed my firs question.

Comment: @DanGetz May very well be, but in any case it doesn't seem to be a very appropriate translation for the example I show in my edit.

Comment: I mean to say, you're right that it doesn't correspond in uses like that. But the idea that this is the only or the main use of the phrase in English is wrong. "It's just that" *would* be appropriate in translations of many of the Portuguese examples on this page. It *can* follow an expression of negative polarity, because it follows an expression of *something*, whether the polarity is positive or negative.

Comment: @DanGetz OK I edged the language.

Comment: Duas respostas excelentes. Difícil saber qual aceitar.

Answer (score 6):

***Só que*** [(see Aulete digital)](http://www.aulete.com.br/s%C3%B3) is a phrasal conjunction that can typically be replaced by ***mas*** (*but*), but it has a narrower meaning than ***mas***. It is used to introduce a fact, idea or argument that somehow goes against what is stated in the previous clause, making it less attractive or less relevant, or frustrating the expectation, intention or plan expressed therein.

In the three examples in the question, *só que* introduces a fact that frustrates the intention or plan expressed in the previous clause:

> Eu pretendia ir com você. Só que, no último minuto, recebi uma notícia que meu primo havia... (I had intended to go with you. But at the last minute I got the news that my cousin had… [the *só que* makes it clear I’m no longer going].)
>
> Tínhamos combinado que cada um pagaria a sua. Só que ao lá chegarmos ele me disse que... (We had agreed that each would pay their own bill. But when we got there he told me…)
>
> Minha esposa queria muito uma esteira rolante para se exercitar em casa. Só que o nosso apartamento é pequeno e não tem espaço suficiente. (My wife wanted a treadmill to exercise at home. But our flat is too small and hasn’t enough room.)

***Só que*** may introduce a fact that diminishes the attractiveness of what is stated previously, not necessarily making it unattractive overall, but serving as warning:

> Este restaurante é muito bom, só que é muito caro. (This restaurant is very good, but it is very expensive (you may want to consider a cheaper alternative).)
>
> Tu podes vir connosco à praia amanhã, só que vais ter de te levantar bem cedo. (You may come with us to the beach tomorrow, but you will have to get up very early.)

***Só que*** may introduce a fact that diminishes the relevance of what was stated before:

> Eu gostaria imenso de ir convosco, só que já assumi outros compromissos. (I’d love to go with you, but I have other commitments already.)
>
> Tudo isso é verdade, só que há outras coisas a considerar. (All that is true, but there are other things to take into account.)

***Só que*** may qualify what was said before, often diminishing its validity or scope:

> Porto e Gaia ficam ambas junto ao rio Douro, só que o Porto fica na margem norte e Gaia na sul. (Oporto and Gaia are both on the Douro river, but Oporto is on the north bank, Gaia on the south one.)
>
> O Porto fica na foz do Douro. Gaia, também, só que do outro lado do rio. (Oporto is on the mouth of the Douro river. Gaia is there too, but across the river.)

Now, I have translated ***só que*** as ***but*** in all my examples. However sometimes ***but*** is not translatable as ***só que***: you’d have to use ***mas***. I suppose what happens here, is that in these examples *mas* highlights some sort of contrast, but in no way diminishes what was said before.

> Na terça não posso ir contigo ao cinema; mas na quarta posso. (I cannot go to the movies with you this Tuesday, but I can on Wednesday.)
>
> Gosto de moela, mas não gosto de fígado. (I like gizzards, but not liver.)

Comment: Boa resposta, mas vendo exemplos no CETEMPúblico parece há casos que não encaixam, como esta «O Cazaquistão também vai votar hoje, só que nesta república, a segunda maior em área da URSS, não se trata de uma opção pela independência, mas da eleição do presidente .» Aqui há apenas uma frustração de uma (putativa) expectativa do leitor. It would also help to see cases where _mas_ cannot be replaced with _só que_.

Comment: @Artefacto Tens razão. Esse exemplo não encaixa bem nas minhas categorias. Há uma "diminuição" da semelhança implicada pelo "também". Tou a pensar em *mas* que não são *só que*: «gosto de moela e coração, mas não gosto de fígado»? *So que* não me soa bem, mas poderia dizer «gosto de moela e coração, só de fígado é que não.» Ah! «Na terça não posso, mas na quarta posso.»

Comment: Não me parece que "diminishing scope/relevance" descreva bem o tipo de qualificação que "só que" faz. Exemplo: «Os portugueses são monárquicos, só que não sabem». A ideia de cancelar uma inferência parece-me uma explicação mais geral, ainda que talvez mais maleável. Uma maneira de conciliar as duas explicações era entender a inferência como parte da afirmação inicial; ao negá-la estaríamos a diminuir-lhe o escopo. Mas parece-me que é um esticão dizer que "os portugueses sabem que são monárquicos" é parte de "os portugueses são monárquicos".

Comment: @Artefacto Sim, contrariar possíveis inferências da frase anterior é uma boa explicação geral. Reduzir o escopo ou relevância funciona nos exemplos em que eu pensei. Fica para amanhã.

Comment: @Artefacto  A frase «Os portugueses são monárquicos, só que não sabem» é apenas um exemplo ou tem algum significado real ?

Comment: @Centaurus Os portugueses não sabem! Tens que perguntar a um espanhol.

Comment: @Jacinto  "Tem piada" a tua resposta. (como, suponho, dizem os portugueses). No Brasil não dizemos "tem piada".

Comment: @Centaurus Foi tirada do CETEMPúblico, não sei o contexto. De qualquer forma pessoalmente não sabia que era monárquico.

Comment: Duas respostas excelentes. Difícil saber qual aceitar.  Obrigado pela contribuição.

Comment: Moeda ao ar. Aqui também se pode dizer "tem graça". É isso que se diz no Brasil?

Comment: @Artefacto Eu pensava-me um republicano circunstancial convicto. Mas às tantas somos monárquicos sem o saber.

Comment: @Jacinto No Brasil diríamos:  muito boa essa, essa é ótima, muito engraçada, num círculo menos formal e sem senhoras por perto "Pô, essa é do ca.....".   Embora "tem piada" ou "tem graça" não sejam idiomáticos em ptBR, qualquer um entenderia o significado.

Comment: @Artefacto  Aqui só um comentário jocoso.  Entrou em vigor no dia primeiro de janeiro, aqui no Brasil, o "Acordo Ortográfico".  Agora todos aqui tem que respeitá-lo, pelo menos no que toca a imprensa. Estivesses tu aqui, terias que mudar teu nome para "Artefato".

Comment: @Centaurus Eh, mas em Portugal o "c" de "artefacto" é lido, portanto o acordo consagra a dupla grafia. Além disso, o vocabulário oficial brasileiro parece incluir também [_artefacto_](http://voc.cplp.org/index.php?action=lemma&lemma=123770), além de [_artefato_](http://voc.cplp.org/index.php?action=lemma&lemma=98747).

Comment: @Artefacto isso quase dava uma boa pergunta ;)